# Dataprep : Invalid array type after run job to excel file

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I try to use array type column in dataprep and it is look good in dataprep display ui as the picture below.
But when I run job output with .csv file, there are invalid value in the array column.
Why does the .csv output different from dataprep display?

[Array in Dataprep display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNxny.jpg)

[Array in csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWJpf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these two columns each contain the complete record...? I also see some non-English characters in there. I suspect something to do with line breaks and/or encoding.

What do you see if you open the CSV file in a *plaintext editor*, instead of Excel?

What edition of Dataprep are you using (click Help => About Dataprep => see the Edition heading)?

What version of Excel are you using to open the CSV file?

Assuming that this is a straight-forward flow with a single dataset and recipe, could you post a few rows of data and the recipe itself (which you can download), for testing purposes?